# DFS locations in Eclipse Europa after accessing Hadoop in a VM

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, virtual-machine

I am very new to hadoop. I need to install it and play around with samples.

SO i referred this [tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html) . I have installed Sandbox given in that tutorial. I need to configure ECLIPSE in windows mentioning VM location as specified in the image below, which is given in the tutorial.
[image]
I have installed eclipse europa and  hadoop plugin.
Then in Map/Reduce Locations i gave VM Ip for host name, Linux user name in UserName and 9001 in Map/Reduce port and 9000 in DFS port.

In Advanced Tab I have set value to the mapred.system.dir as /hadoop/mapred/system

and there is no hadoop.job.ugi to give username.
[image]

After i click ok, I couldn't get HDFS file system under my DFS locations in ECLIPSE.
Please help me on this

Comment: May be your ports are different than depicted in the tutorial, you can see the values of ports from "core-site.xml" and "mapred-site.xml".

Comment: @Alper: I searched entire folder. I can't find xml you specified. :(

Comment: it may be in the HADOOP_HOME/conf, could you check that?

Comment: @Alper: Yeah there is Hadoop-default.xml. But i can't find Dfs Master port or Map Reduce Master port

Comment: I too had struggled with this but could not find anything. If you want to learn, I would suggest use cygwin and set up a single node cluster on windows. This link should help you: http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html. I think this tutorial is using hadoop-0.19.0, but feel free to use the latest stable version. Even better would be if you can set up hadoop on ubuntu-linux. Here is a very nice tutorial: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too ran into the same issue. I installed RedHad cgywin (openssh and openssl packages) and updated the "Path" environment variable with a path to cgywin/bin (`c:\rhcygwin\bin`). Then my Eclipse DFS location was able to connect to Hadoop on the Virtual Machine. Once that was successful I saw the option "hadoop.job.ugi".

http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html describes installing cgywin.

Note: I am running the Hadoop VM on Windows Vista.

Comment: Make sure to mark the openssh boxes while installing Cygwin

Answer (score 4):

I also got the same problem. The problem here is not related to hadoop configuration but eclipse. To fix this, go to "**\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.apache.hadoop.eclipse\locations**". Here open the XML file and just add the property "**hadoop.job.ugi**" with value "**hadoop-user,ABC**" and then restart your eclipse. It worked for me.

I tried by giving just one value i.e. without ABC but it dint work and I dont know the significance of this comma separated value but since I have just started the tutorial I hope to get this answer soon :)

Answer (score 0):

I spawned Eclipse from within Cygwin and it worked fine for me (i.e. I could see the "hadoop.job.ugi" parameter). Also, I didn't make any changes to my PATH environment variable.